# I want to create 256 color variations of my image

Tags: image, image-processing, photoshop

I have an jpeg image of dimensions say, *mxn* pixels. The content of this image is just plain white color completely covering it.

I want to do the following batch task with it:
I want to take the image as an input and repaint it with a given intensity.I could achieve this through **Paint or Photoshop** but that only works for one image at a time. Instead I want a batch function to process image 256 times and store the rsult 
Now, I want to do this task 256 times for 256 pixel intensities on Grayscale and the save the result with a name as `<Image_name_<Intensity_Value>>` in jpeg.

Comment: What language would you like to use to accomplish this task?

Comment: @MarkRansom :   Although I am familiar with C, C++, Java, any solution involving an image processor or less tasks is appreciated because of time constraints. For ex I can work in Photosop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this with ImageMagick which is free and available for Windows from [here](http://www.imagemagick.org):

```
@echo off
for /L %%a IN (0,1,255) do convert -size 200x300 xc:"rgb(%%a,%%a,%%a)" FRED_%%a.jpg
```

It gives you 256 files, each 200 pixels wide and 300 pixels high, which look like this:

[image]

Here is a list of the files

```
 Volume in drive E is VBOX_tmp
 Volume Serial Number is 0100-0002

 Directory of E:\

06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_0.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_1.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_10.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_100.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_101.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_102.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_103.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_104.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_105.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_106.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_107.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_108.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_109.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_11.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_110.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_111.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_112.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_113.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_114.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_115.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_116.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_117.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_118.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_119.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_12.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_120.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_121.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_122.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_123.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_124.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_125.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               397 FRED_126.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               397 FRED_127.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               396 FRED_128.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               397 FRED_129.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_13.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               397 FRED_130.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_131.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_132.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_133.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_134.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_135.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_136.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_137.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_138.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_139.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_14.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_140.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_141.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_142.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_143.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_144.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_145.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_146.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_147.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_148.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_149.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_15.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_150.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_151.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_152.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_153.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_154.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_155.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_156.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_157.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_158.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_159.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_16.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_160.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_161.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_162.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_163.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_164.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_165.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_166.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_167.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_168.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_169.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_17.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_170.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_171.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_172.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_173.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_174.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_175.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_176.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_177.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_178.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_179.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_18.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_180.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_181.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_182.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_183.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_184.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_185.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_186.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_187.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_188.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_189.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_19.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_190.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_191.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_192.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_193.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_194.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_195.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_196.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_197.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_198.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_199.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_2.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_20.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_200.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_201.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_202.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_203.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_204.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_205.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_206.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_207.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_208.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_209.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_21.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_210.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_211.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_212.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_213.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_214.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_215.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_216.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_217.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_218.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_219.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_22.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_220.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_221.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_222.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_223.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_224.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_225.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_226.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_227.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_228.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_229.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_23.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_230.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_231.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_232.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_233.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_234.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_235.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_236.jpg
06/05/2015  19:32               398 FRED_237.jpg
06/05/2015  19:32               398 FRED_238.jpg
06/05/2015  19:32               398 FRED_239.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_24.jpg
06/05/2015  19:32               398 FRED_240.jpg
06/05/2015  19:32               398 FRED_241.jpg
06/05/2015  19:32               398 FRED_242.jpg
06/05/2015  19:32               398 FRED_243.jpg
06/05/2015  19:32               398 FRED_244.jpg
06/05/2015  19:32               398 FRED_245.jpg
06/05/2015  19:32               398 FRED_246.jpg
06/05/2015  19:32               398 FRED_247.jpg
06/05/2015  19:32               398 FRED_248.jpg
06/05/2015  19:32               398 FRED_249.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_25.jpg
06/05/2015  19:32               398 FRED_250.jpg
06/05/2015  19:32               398 FRED_251.jpg
06/05/2015  19:32               398 FRED_252.jpg
06/05/2015  19:32               398 FRED_253.jpg
06/05/2015  19:32               398 FRED_254.jpg
06/05/2015  19:32               398 FRED_255.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_26.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_27.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_28.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_29.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_3.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_30.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_31.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_32.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_33.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_34.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_35.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_36.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_37.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_38.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_39.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_4.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_40.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_41.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_42.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_43.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_44.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_45.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_46.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_47.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_48.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_49.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_5.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_50.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_51.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_52.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_53.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_54.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_55.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_56.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_57.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_58.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_59.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_6.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_60.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_61.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_62.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_63.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_64.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_65.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_66.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_67.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_68.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_69.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_7.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_70.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_71.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_72.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_73.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_74.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_75.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_76.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_77.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_78.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_79.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_8.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_80.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_81.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_82.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_83.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_84.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_85.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_86.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_87.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_88.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_89.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_9.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_90.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_91.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_92.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_93.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_94.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_95.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_96.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_97.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_98.jpg
06/05/2015  19:31               398 FRED_99.jpg
             256 File(s)        101,882 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  75,015,933,952 bytes free
```

Comment: Thank You for the reply. I will try your suggestion then reply the result

Comment: I am confused about the command. How do I give that in cmd? And where have you specified the source image name?

Comment: If you should have any trouble installing ImageMagick, the last one listed is most likely to work - I think it's called static or portable.

Comment: You can either save the conmand in a file called `GO.BAT` and then type `GO` or you can type it in at the prompt by hand, but if you do that you must change all `%%` into `%`. Don't ask me why Windows is so illogical.

Comment: I installed it successfully. It shows all the options on typing convert image: but the command @echo off
for /L %%a IN (0,1,255) do convert -size 200x300 xc:"rgb(%%a,%%a,%%a)" FRED_%%a.jpg  is what I am confused about

Comment: Okay. It perfectly works! One more thing: Can you throw some light on the command you specified. Where is the imagemagic being given the task in the command?

Comment: `convert` is a part of the ImageMagick suite - along with `identify` and `mogrify`. Try `identify someImage.jpg` or `identify -verbose anyImage.png`

Comment: Okay, I figured it out myself. Thank You for the "quick" answer

Comment: No problems - glad it worked out for you. Questions are free, so go ahead and ask if you get stuck. Good luck!